# How does an object reference itself in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, reference, this

I was experimenting with inheritance in javascript, and wrote those two functions:

```
Object.prototype.inherits=function(obj){this.prototype=new obj;}
Object.prototype.pass=function(obj){obj.prototype=new this;}
```

This code works very well:

```
Dog.inherits(Animal);
```

But the following fails:

```
Animal.pass(Dog);
```

As I understand it, my pass functions doesn't work, because "this" isn't a reference to the object instance itself? If that's the case, how can I reference the object from within itself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually the two are doing exactly the same:

```
Dog.prototype = new Animal;
```

The `this` value inside the methods will refer to the *base object* where the reference was invoked, in the case of:

```
Dog.inherits(Animal);
```

The `this` value will refer to the `Dog` constructor function, and the `obj` argument will be the `Animal` function.

When you call:

```
Animal.pass(Dog);
```

The `this` value will refer to the `Animal` function, doing at the end exactly the same thing as the `inherits` method, but the other way around.

I would recommend you to *not* extend the `Object.prototype` object, because it can cause you a lot of problems, for example those two properties will be enumerated in any `for-in` loop, e.g.:

```
for (var prop in {}) { // <-- an empty object!
  alert(prop); // will alert 'inherits' and 'pass'
}
```

All objects inherit from `Object.prototype`, and it seems that you intend to use those methods only on Function objects, it would be safer to extend the `Function.prototype` object, or implement the methods as functions that take two parameters.

Comment: Yeah, both functions work fine, guess I made a mistake when I tested it... Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, with test code like:

```
function Animal() {}
Animal.prototype.isanimal= 1;
function Dog() {}
Animal.pass(Dog);
Dog.prototype.isdog= 2;
alert(new Dog().isanimal); // 1
alert(new Dog().isdog);    // 2
```

However, bear in mind that `new this` or `new obj` will call the function `this/obj`, creating a new full instance. If you have constructor code in that function that expects to receive some arguments, or sets up instance state, you can end up with problems. To create a new `this` without calling `this` as a function you can use a different constructor that does nothing:

```
function nonconstructor() {}
nonconstructor.prototype= this.prototype;
obj.prototype= new nonconstructor();
```

Also, you should avoid prototyping onto `Object`. This will cause trouble for code using `Object` as a general-purpose lookup map. As you only seem to be working with constructor-functions, prototyping onto `Function` should meet your needs and is much safer.